# how to finding source link in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, links

In my regular works i am linking some sheets cells in to other sheets.Like Sheet1 A5 linked in Sheet2 d3. in this way in a work book i have some many interlink pages in a single work book , some times external work books links also we are using.But when ever i want to go to the source cell i am copying the link & going to the original sheet,using Find option i am doing that.But i would like to is there any  other options to go to the source cell directly by clicking in my present work book cells.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows, press
    Ctrl+[

this should take to the linked cell.